# Compressing TCP in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

We have .NET 4.0 application using Entity Framework. Application connects remotely over TCP to the SQL Server. When on LAN, it's fast, but over internet the traffic is very high.

All we would like to do is to turn on some `TCP compression` but it looks like that SQL Server 2008 doesn't provide this feature.

What's the simplest solution to make TCP communication compressed?

Comment: hint -- insulting people who are helping you will not get you far on this website.

Comment: Also, if you are not seeing a problem on the LAN but are seeing it on a WAN then the issue has to do with latency -- you are making lots of small little connections and it runs slow on the WAN.  Compression will not help with this issue (in fact it might make it worse.)   Run a profile on your program and see what Entity is really doing under the hood.  It will make you cry.

Comment: This question screams 'wrong architectural choices' that unfortunately don't have a simple solution. Several people tried to tell you that already and simply dismissing their advice isn't going to make the problem disappear

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to solve the problem on the wrong level / layer. Profile your communication with SQL server and start to think about optimizations. That is the only valid point to start. Incorrect usage of EF can lead in terrible chatty and slow communication with SQL server and that is something that will simply not be solved by any compression because chatty sequential communication means multiple unnecessary roundtrips to database where each single roundtrip will increase the duration of processing by its latency. I have already seen solutions (and some of them I did myself) where incorrect usage of EF created thousands of lazy loading queries within single request processing.

And yes it can end up in replacing part of your EF code with stored procedures and custom queries and in the worst case with abandoning whole EF.

If your problem is amount of transferred data it is again time to think about optimization and reducing amount of transferred data to only needed subset or perhaps using some preprocessing on SQL server in stored procedure or view. Btw. such thinking should be done during application design where you should think about target environment where the application will run.

Edit:

One more note. It is not very common to communicate with database over WAN. Usually such requirement leads to implementing another tier with business logic sitting on the server in LAN with SQL server. This business logic tier exposes web services to client on WAN. This architecture can reduce latency when communicating with database a lot and in the same time a correct architecture of message exchanging between client and service can lead to additional improvements.

Comment: +1 nice, well considered answer

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to say!

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server uses the TDS protocal.

It doesn't care whether you use TCP or Named Pipes or "the force" to get data from A to B

You'd need to enable or set up some kind of [compression](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tcp%20compression) (Google search):

- at the OS level
- the interface/hardware level
- the network level

Comment: Too generic. Sorry, but useless.

Comment: @James: I'll spell it out in simple terms for you: "this is not a SQL Server problem". Vote to close and -1

Comment: @James - gbn answer is totally on point.  Your question has nothing to do with sql server or entity framework (besides entity framework being the wrong platform to use as it always has problems like this) -- if you want an answer to this question take it to the hardware and sys admin sites -- super user or server fault.  You won't get much help here.